# Upload and Download Only in a Document Library in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, 2016

How do I create a Document Library with Upload and Download only permissions in SharePoint Online?

I do not want the users to be able to edit online, unless they save the file (download the file) to their local computer and then have the ability to upload.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could create the custom permission level and grant the custom permission in the document library.

You could create the custom permission level as below:

List Permissions: Add Items, View Items and Open Items.

Site Permission: View Pages, Open.

Then use the unique permission in the document library and grant the user with the custom permission level.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this type of requirement by **Creating custom level permission** and **Breaking Inheritance on Document Library**.

**Create a permission level:**

Create custom permission level by checking check boxes of **Add Items** and **View Items**. follow below steps:

- Open the site collection site (the root site not a subsite)
- Go to site setting.
- below Users and Permission > Click on Site Permission.
- From the above ribbon, > click on permission level to be able to create a new permission level.

[image]

**Reference**:

1. [How to create and edit permission levels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/how-to-create-and-edit-permission-levels).
2. [Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels).

**Breaking Inheritance and add permissions using newly created permission level**:

Then break the permissions on document library and grant the permissions on this library by using newly created permission level.

**Reference**:

[Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question correctly, you want to disable online browsing/editing experience of document library.

Disable Office Online (Browser Mode) for a Document Library

Go to the library where you want to change the browser behavior. Click on Gear Icon > 
Library Settings
[image]

Choose Advanced Settings

[image]

Under Opening Documents in the Browser, choose Open in the client application button. 
[image]

Click OK